# I am trying to pass an array to a function and continue to use it, but I always get the wrong number of elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to iterate over an array within an export function, which is passed from the outside via another function. In this function, data is fetched from the server via axios and packed into a hook. This hook (array) is then sent to the second function (table). Now it is so that the correct array arrives with all values, but an "old" array is used within the table (see number of elements)

The array that was passed contains the correct number:
[image]

But as soon as I put this in a hook, the number is no longer correct
[image]

Comment: did you try to set `rows` in `useEffect` hook?

Comment: `But as soon as I put this in a hook, the number is no longer correct` what hook? Both images show same code.

Comment: Where in the functional component EnhancedTable have you called the function `setRows()`? My guess is that `rows` is being updated by `setRows` after the component rendered and `rows` was initialized.